# Sorting and paginate large MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, database, pagination, sphinx

I have a very large MySQL table (300 million rows with 12 columns).

I want my users to be able to sort the entire table on one of these columns ASC and DESC. My PHP/HTML code should then show the top 10 results to the user, then the user should be able to pagination further in.

As you understand, without any optimization this will take very, very long time to do.

I'm using Sphinx at the moment, which speeds this process up significant. But it's still not fast enough.

My database data only change once a month.

What would you suggest in order to improve the performance for this? If you can give me advice how to optimize Sphinx, that would be nice.

But any advice is welcome, I dont have to use Sphinx for this.

Thanks!
Joel

Comment: What kind of index do you use? Could you post an example of your select to fetch the top 10?

Comment: Set an `index` on each column You would like to sort by or search the values through. Are You using some ORM or just pure `mysql_` functions? Or do You use some models describing DB tables? As Andreas proposed, show us Your SQL and PHP where You fetch the data.

Comment: Currently, I'm using Sphinx as index. So, I'm also fetching the data through Sphinx. With that said, I dont have any select example =/

Comment: I second the suggestion to post examples. At the moment we can but guess the queries you are running. Its like asking someone to help you make your car go faster, but refusing to show them the car, or even tell them what make it is. They cant even begin to guess what would be suitable

Answer (score -1):

Just use [standard pagination](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wd4fE5fk-fk).

Comment: NemanjaLazic, isnt that a basic pagination tutorial? What I'm looking for is improve the performance for my huge table.

Comment: Answer with no content and a broken link.